# How to understand "bit rich coming from you"

Tags: sentence-meaning

> ... said Ron, "You know we're not supposed to do spells outside school-"
>
> "Bit rich coming from you," said Harry, staring at the floating car.
>
> "Oh, this doesn't count," said Ron."We are only borrowing this, it's dad's, we didn't enchant it. But doing magic in front of those Muggles you live ...
>
> "I told you , I didn't -- ... " (said by Harry)

"Bit rich coming from you" looks like an incomplete sentence in spoken English. Is it like saying: *it's a bit rich/expensive thing coming from you*?

Comment: I haven't read the book, and you haven't provided much context, but the meaning of **rich** there seems to be "amusingly ironic".   The antecedent of the implied "it" is something previously said by Ron.  "coming from" means "coming out of your mouth" or "for you to have said".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I just added more context in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an implied "That is a..."

It is an [idiom](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/That%27s+rich!) and doesn't mean that anything is expensive.

Comment: oh, I don't even realise it's an idiom! It means entirely diferent thing from my understanding originally! Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

"Rich" is, in this context, used to mean "hypocritical". There's no requirement that utterances be complete sentences; if Harry has said "A bit hypocritical, coming from you", that would be a perfectly fine thing to say. A "That is" at the beginning would be understood.